# android bind service to activity

Tags: android, service, bind

I have seen several similar examples here but can't seem to get my service to bind with activity.

I am getting the error

> "android.os.binderproxy cannot be cast to IC_CommissaryService".

My service looks like this:

```
public class IC_CommissaryService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();          

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder 
    {       
        IC_CommissaryService getService() 
        {
            return IC_CommissaryService.this;
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
    }

    private boolean SendOrderToServer(int orderID)
    {
        /* do stuff*/
    }
```

}

and my activity looks like this:

```
public class SubmitOrders extends Activity 
{
    IC_CommissaryService ICservice;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        Intent serviceintent = new Intent(this, IC_CommissaryService.class);
        serviceintent.putExtra("binded", true);
        bindService(serviceintent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) 
        {
            Log.e("TEST", "SERVICE CONNECTED");
            try
            {
                ICservice =(IC_CommissaryService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
                for(int i = 0; i < Submitorders.size(); i++)
                {
                    ICservice.SendOrderToServer(Submitorders.get(i).intValue());                                                
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("Error", "Error connecting service: " + ex.getMessage());
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) 
        {           
        }
    };
}
```

I am getting the error in my activity on the line `ICservice =(IC_CommissaryService.LocalBinder)service).getService();`

I think I have done the same as people already suggested in other posts so any help please?

thanks

Comment: use `ICservice = (LocalBinder)service.getService();` instead of `ICservice =(IC_CommissaryService.LocalBinder)service).getService();`

Comment: Just take a look [link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

Comment: @imrankhan i cannot use localbinder.getService because there is no instance of localbinder - this line of code is trying to create that instance

Comment: @Sebs_Jedi - your link does not show how to bind to a service, only how to start a service from activity, this is not what i want

Comment: @user1280736 : use this `ICservice = (LocalBinder)service.getService();`

Comment: @imrankhan i tried that already and get the same error

Comment: for linking in maifiest add  <service
   android:name="NAME OF SERVIC CLASS"></service>

Comment: @Sebs_Jedi, i already have everything required in manifest etc to get service working - i can get it to work by calling startservice from my activity, but i don't want to do it this way - i want to bind to activity to call only specific functions in service

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem. I just figured it out today. Please look at the parts annotated with `<<=====` below. I hope it helps.

```
public class PracticeServiceBindingActivity extends ListActivity {
       private MyService.MyBinder service;   <<====
       ....

       private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection( ){

               public void onServiceConnected (ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                      setService(MyService.MyBinder) service;  <<====
               ....
               }
       }

       public void onCreate(....) {

               ...
               public MyService.MyBinder getService(){     <<=====
                      return service;
               }
               public void setService(MyService.MyBinder service) {   <<=====
                      this.service = service;
               }
       }

}
```

Comment: It didn't work. How is `setService(MyService.MyBinder) service;` a valid statement?

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the Bound Services [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Creating):

> If your service is private to your own application and runs in the
>   same process as the client (which is common), you should create your
>   interface by extending the Binder class and returning an instance of
>   it from onBind().

Remove the android:process attribute in  in AndroidManifest.ml to make the service run in the same process. I had the same problem today it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

These are the abstract classes that I use to solve this problem:
https://gist.github.com/frenchie4111/6086c6e4327d7936364a

Just extend both these classes with your service and activity (You can change the fragment from a fragment to an activity with ease). And make sure that in your service/fragment onCreate you set the serviceClass like so:

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstance ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstance );
    this.serviceClass = IC_CommissaryService.class;
}
```